# Recognize sub image

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have a quite simple task: the goal is to detect an image pattern inside another image. In particular, I have to identify the correct side of a cassette drug-of-abuse test from a picture acquired from scanner with the lowest error rate possible. I’m using AForge.NET library with C#.

**DOA Test picture:**

[link http://www.atbsrl.com/media/SO/doa-test-sample.png](http://www.atbsrl.com/media/SO/doa-test-sample.png)

**Test in Progress picture:**

[link http://www.atbsrl.com/media/SO/Schema03.png](http://www.atbsrl.com/media/SO/Schema03.png)

The cassette faces are pretty similar, but the first (A side) has 3 adulteration strips (with colored areas) and the other only drug-of-abuse strips (B side).

To be pretty sure to recognize the A side, I tried to mix different approaches, e.g. color matching and template matching, but at the moment my tests with AForge.NET didn’t produce the expected results because of the variability of the input image.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't underestimate the difficulty of tasks ;)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt - I seriously laughed out loud when I read "simple".

Comment: Well it is not *superhard* (like recognizing any cat in any image). It is a well-defined problem with a known set of inputs and not that many variation. It is a 2D problem. The colors are somethat well defined. Surely doable.

Comment: @RobAu: That's why I merely suggested not to *underestimate* tasks, and left qualification of the difficulty out of it. Superhard? No. Simple? No. Depends on the programmer probably. And apparently definitely not simple for the poster.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, actually it's not a trivial task at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a convolutional neural network.  There is almost nothing you can do with classical image processing that would have as low an error rate.

To apply this, collect as many images as possible (preferably a thousand or more; a hundred may not be enough, ten thousand is ideal) of each side, and make a text file with filenames and labels as to which side they are from (0 for front or 1 for back).  Then, take an off-the-shelf package like [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) or [libccv](http://libccv.org/) and train it on this data set.  You can use just about any network model but CaffeNet in Caffe will work fine, follow [this tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html) to retrain a fully trained CaffeNet for your application (which is easier than starting from scratch, and can work with less data).  To get started, it may be easiest to just launch an AWS instance which Caffe preinstalled, like [this one](http://blog.titocosta.com/post/110345699197/public-ec2-ami-with-torch-and-caffe-deep-learning).  Considering the nature of your data, I think you will easily get to <1% error rate (or possibly much lower, if you have more data).

If you can modify the object being detected, you could use a simpler algorithm: for example color each face, or put fiducial marks or simple barcodes.

Comment: Unfortunately the media cannot be modified in any way.

Comment: How could be used to solve the problem? I'm googling about it and seems very efficient but complex to implement. What about the "training" step?

Comment: @mdoneda: I added some more details on how to apply neural networks, please have a look.